# What is the best way to turn the chunks of jaggery into fine powder?

Tags: equipment, sugar, indian-cuisine, grinding

I have big chunks of jaggery. I want to turn them into fine powder.

What is the best way to turn the chunks of jaggery into their powdered form?

Comment: please tag the question yourself. I couldn't find any more relevant tags.

Comment: Relevant: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35140/does-jaggery-need-to-be-soaked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't get to an Indian grocery very often, so I buy a huge block of rock-like jaggery to keep at home. Over time, I chisel off some more manageable pieces, and turn those pieces into powder as needed. So, my process is:

1. Literally a hammer and chisel for the big block. Sometimes sawing with a serrated blade is useful, too.
2. To make powder from a chunk, I use a box grater with the "zester" or "star grater" side of the tool. Do **not** use the "shredding" side(s) of the box. I have not had luck with a food processor; the jaggery is too hard, and sticks to the blades rather than getting cut up. It stops making progress long before it's a powder.

Example of the grater side to use: ([source](https://chatelaine.com/food/kitchen-tips/box-grater/))

[image]

Some misc notes:

- Lots of recipes don't actually need a fine powder. You can just dissolve a chunk of jaggery in (hot) liquid, which may be easier.
- In a pinch, a wide hammer (such as the flat side of a meat tenderizer) or rolling pin can be good for making powder. Put some smallish pieces of jaggery on a flat hard surface, and **roll** the hammer over them, crushing them. Do not whack in a hammering motion, just press down hard and roll it. This will not produce quite as fine a powder as the grating method, but it's pretty good.
- It might be better to get a microplane-style "hand zester" and just use that on the big block directly. I haven't bothered buying one, yet.
- You might have luck with a Parmesan grater — they are designed to turn a hard cheese into powder, which is not too far off from jaggery. Likewise, a nutmeg grater would have the right effect, too (though a little small). These all have essentially the same design as the "zester" side of a box grater, pictured, above; that's the important bit.
- [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ND5uSWbjfpY) recommends microwaving the jaggery to soften it, then you can crumble it directly, rather than grating. It won't make quite as fine a powder still, but pretty good.
- As others have mentioned, jaggery comes in various forms. Some softer/harder, bigger/smaller, etc. If you have the ability to visit the store as needed, you can maybe find something less labor-intensive (:

Answer (score 3):

I usually grate my jaggery block on a microplane grater although your standard cheese grater will work too. I haven't tried a food processor yet, although that would probably work.

Next time I'm going to get granulated palm sugar as I've found working with a jaggery block too much hassle.

Comment: I'm fairly certain (though can't recall source, sorry) that jaggery is hard enough to damage food processor blades, so try at your own risk.  I think the microplane is the way to go.

Comment: I think it depends on the jaggery. My block is fairly moist and more sticky than hard, but others have been harder. None of the ones I have had seemed hard enough to damage a processor blade but I would not assume anything.

Answer (score 1):

A mortar and pestle should do a pretty good job also!